# adding react app to static portfolio website

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hi I'm new to react and I'm trying to add a project I made to my static portfolio.

In other words I need a way to have my project in a separated page like "portfolio.com/project-name" but I don't know how to do it.

the portfolio is running trough an Apache web server on my raspberry pi

[Portfolio](https://github.com/Arm0ny/portfolio)
[React App](https://github.com/Arm0ny/quotes_app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way you can do this is to embed the react app in a fullscreen iFrame. First you'd need to host the react app on a web host that supports it (replit maybe), and then you would stick this in the html.

```
<iframe src="https://react-app-url" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
Iframes are not supported on your browser
</iframe>
```

I am sorry if this does not work (I have not tested it) but I use replit a lot and replit has great support for React so this is probably what I would do in your situation.

Comment: what if I use apache to host my portfolio? I have it running on my raspberry, do I need another domain name or can I use the one I'm using for the portfolio?

Comment: nope, just host the react on replit and put the iframe html into your portfolio wherever you need it!

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial explains how to deploy a React app to a static *GitHub Pages* site:
https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages

I would guess that it wouldn't work well if your app uses routing because reloading the page when the active path is not the root one would fail.